# DOMXPath query attribute that contains Unicode character

Tags: php, html, xpath, unicode, domxpath

Is it possible to access element that contain Unicode class name?

I'm actually [accessing this site](https://www.honestbee.my/en/groceries/stores/bens-independent-grocer/products/720365), but their class name are prefixed with Unicode character U+1F41D HONEYBEE

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.honestbee.my/en/groceries/stores/bens-independent-grocer/products/720365');
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new \DOMXpath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->query("//[@class='ap0']");
if (!is_null($elements)) {
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        echo "<br/>[". $element->nodeName. "]";

        $nodes = $element->childNodes;
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it throws error

```
ErrorException  : DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression                                                                                                     
 at /paht/to/test-dom.php:83                                                                        
   79|         $doc->loadHTML($html);                                       
   80|                                                                      
   81|         $xpath = new \DOMXpath($doc);                                
   82|                                                                      
 > 83|         $elements = $xpath->query("//[@class='ap0']");             
   84|         if (!is_null($elements)) {                                   
   85|             foreach ($elements as $element) {                        
   86|                 echo "<br/>[". $element->nodeName. "]";              
   87|                                                                      

Exception trace:

1   DOMXPath::query("//[@class='ap0']")                                  
    /paht/to/test-dom.php:83
```

I was referring to [emoji code here](https://www.iemoji.com/view/emoji/663/animals-nature/honeybee), tried with `\uD83Dap0` also not working

Comment: Have you tried `"//[@class='&#x1F41D;ap0']"`? Not sure where you got D83D, which is a different character.

Comment: Tried a few different things, nothing seems to work. Closest I got was `$elements = $xpath->query("//*[@class[contains(., 'ap0')]]");`

Comment: @miken32 Thanks. But the `contains` can't make sure target the correct element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I went down a rabbit hole of character encodings and whatnot, before trying `$doc->saveHTML()` and noticing that all the Unicode characters were corrupted. My guess is that `DOMDocument::loadHTML` treats everything as ISO-8859-1, which was the default encoding for HTML 4. So, by adding an XML prologue we can trick it into parsing as UTF-8. This allows you to search by class name, no matter what characters it uses:

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.honestbee.my/en/groceries/stores/bens-independent-grocer/products/720365');
$prologue = '<?xml encoding="UTF-8">';
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($prologue . $html);
$xpath = new \DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("//div[@class='ap0']");
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    echo "<br/>[". $element->nodeName. "]";
    $nodes = $element->childNodes;
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        echo $node->nodeValue. " \n";
    }
}
```

It's also worth noting that your "invalid expression" error was not due to the bee, but rather because you didn't have an element name in your query. In my answer I used div, if you want to search all elements you can use *.

Comment: You saved me with this answer!

Comment: I was experiencing encoding issue when reading Unicode text from HTML. Your answer was helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm using [Rct567/DomQuery](https://github.com/Rct567/DomQuery/issues/4). The author already fix the issue.

For those who facing the same issue, I recommend to use this package.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to replace the specific, known, unicode character attribute with an ASCII string. Do this on-the-fly, just before executing XPATH query.

Example: $html = preg_replace("/ap0/u", 'Beeap0123456', $html);

Alternatively, str_replace function should be able to replace an array of unicode attribute names with a mapped array of ASCII attribute names.

Then the XPATH query expression would be a straight-forward ASCII one: '//*[@class="Beeap0123456"]'

(Adding a unique string to the replacement ASCII string might reduce the chance of confusion when the document contains other similar attributes.)